# Nesting Data in Mongoose variable

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

How do you declare the type for a variable in a Mongoose schema which also has nested variables? If it's possible, what would be the correct way of adding data to it when creating the object.

This schema is provided by the Mongoose Docs and I am confused about how you would add data and/ or declare a type for the 'meta' variable.

```
var Comments = new Schema({
    title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : [Comments]
  , meta      : {
        votes : Number
      , favs  : Number
    }
});

mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meta is type Object. It has 2 properties, `votes`, and `favs`, both of them are numbers. If you want to create a blog post with meta, is as simple as:

```
new BlogPost({
  title: 'new blog post',
  body: 'nice SEO'
  meta: {
    votes: 3,
    favs: 1
  }
})
```

If you want to be more explict when declaring, you can declare meta like this:

```
meta: {
  type: Object,
  votes : Number,
  favs  : Number
}
```